# New BigQuery pricing 'tiers'

Tags: google-bigquery

According to the [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries), a new tiered pricing model will be introduced for BigQuery on January 1st 2016.

We'd like to be able to predict any cost implications this may have to our applications. So we've taken a look at the JSON response for some of our more complex queries to see what 'tier' has been assigned to it.

The `billingTier` tier is clearly visible in the JSON response.

```
200 OK
- Show headers -
{
  "kind": "bigquery#job",
  [...]
  "totalBytesProcessed": "45319172942",
  "query": {
  "totalBytesProcessed": "45319172942",
  "totalBytesBilled": "45319454720",
  "billingTier": 1,
  "cacheHit": false
}
```

Is this just a default tier assigned (tier 1) until the new pricing model kicks in on Jan 1st 2016, or is it a true indication of the tier assigned to the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `billingTier` field is a true indicator of the tier assigned to the query according to our upcoming pricing structure. If this field is set to 1, then your query would be billed at current (tier 1) rates under the new pricing structure.

Note that billing tier is computed separately on each invocation of a query, so there's no strict guarantee that the same query will always fall in the same billing tier. I'd recommend spot-checking a reasonable sample of your queries to get a general sense of where your workload will fall under the new pricing structure.

Comment: @Jeremy Condit would it be possible to display the billingTier field in the Query History section of the Web UI? Currently we can see the Job ID, Start Time, End Time, Bytes Processed but not the Billing Tier.

Comment: On our list. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @JeremyCondit January 1st 2016 is coming and we would like to know quickly if our ETL queries will be impacted by this pricing change. Can we expect to have the billingTier field in the Query History section soon?

Comment: Thanks for the ping. Will try to add it soon.

Comment: @JeremyCondit Do you an ETA on this new feature ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested i've written a simple script that if run daily will add audit data to a table in big query containing homogenized queries by user. We are using this to audit query costs and determine which tables may require sharding.

https://gist.github.com/ericuldall/ac475fe71d0ee2f3a5f0

This script is estimating costs around $5/TB of data billable.

## Audit Data Table Schema

> job_id STRING  NULLABLE
> user    STRING  NULLABLE
> size_in_gb  FLOAT   NULLABLE
> estimated_cost  FLOAT   NULLABLE
> sql STRING  NULLABLE
> timestamp   TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE